# LINQ Select and Where not correctly returning any results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to select out only certain prescreeners that a respondent has done, but have been unable to do so with my code.

CODE:

```
 IEnumerable<PreScreener> testin = new List<PreScreener>();
                for (int i = 0; i < respondent.PreScreenerResponses.Count; i++)
                {
                    testin = project.PreScreeners.Where(x => x.Id == respondent.PreScreenerResponses[i].PreScreenerId);
                }
```

MODELS:

```
public class PreScreener : IHasId, IHasProjectId
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public int? ProjectId { get; set; }

        public string ExternalId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? PartialCount { get; set; }

        public int? DisqualifiedCount { get; set; }

        public int? CompleteCount { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

        public List<PreScreenerQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
    }



public class PreScreenerResponse : IHasId, IHasProjectId
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }

    public int? PreScreenerId { get; set; }

    public int? RespondentId { get; set; }

    public string Ip { get; set; }

    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public double? Latitude { get; set; }

    public double? Longitude { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<short, PreScreenerQuestionResponse> Response { get; set; }
}
```

Respondent.PreScreenerResponses[i] <--Prescreeners Responses to Prescreeners 
Project.PreScreeners[i] <-- All of the Prescreeners belonging to the project

I quite simply just want to take all of the Prescreeners and put them into a List that will also include the Respondents responses. I figured I will make a new List then just combine the two different lists, but my select Where isn't working I always get an empty testin list.

EDITED CODE BASED ON RESPONSES:

I tried this to no avail

```
        IEnumerable<PreScreener> testin = new List<PreScreener>();
        testin = project.PreScreeners.Where(p => respondent.PreScreenerResponses
                                                            .Select(r => r.PreScreenerId)
                                                                .Contains(p.Id));
```

The Answer that worked is Checked off below!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for loop` is unnecessary. Just use this:

```
testin = project.PreScreeners.Where(x => respondent.PreScreenerResponses.Any(psr => psr.PreScreenerId == x.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: The best overload method match for PreScreenerResponse.Contains has some invalid arguments error

Comment: I tried your new edit it has a new error. Cannot convert lambda expression to type Response because it is not a delegate type. It squiggles underneath psr => psr.PreScreenerId == x.Id

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < respondent.PreScreenerResponses.Count; i++)
{
    testin = project.PreScreeners.Where(x => x.Id == respondent.PreScreenerResponses[i].PreScreenerId);
}
```

this is *overwriting* `testin` on every loop.

{analyzing further to provide sometihng that's actually helpful}

I *think* you want:

```
project.PreScreeners
       .Where(p => respondent.PreScreenerResponses
                             .Select(r => r.PreScreenerId)
                             .Contains(p.Id)
             )
```

or altrenately

```
project.PreScreeners
       .Join(respondent.PreScreenerResponses,
             p => p.Id
             r => r.PreScreenerId
            )
       .Select((p, r) => p);   // select just the PreScreener
```

Comment: I used you method without using the for loop and the testin is still null. I can physically go into the dubugger and looke at respondent and look at project and physically see they indeed do share a common exact match id. But testing is always null. I will repost new code above

Comment: `Where` can never return null.  It may return an empty collection, but not `null`.

Comment: Sorry about that it is returning empty collection

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning you list each time you iterate through your for loop. I think you want to do this instead:

```
IEnumerable<PreScreener> testin = new List<PreScreener>();
for (int i = 0; i < respondent.PreScreenerResponses.Count; i++)
{
    testin.AddRange(project.PreScreeners.Where(x => x.Id == respondent.PreScreenerResponses[i].PreScreenerId));
}
```

Comment: When I do testin.AddRange() I get an error. Prescreener does not contain a definition for AddRange and no extension method AddRange accepting a first argument of type PreScreener could be found.

Comment: That error doesn't really make sense... You shouldn't be calling AddRange on Prescrenner. It should be getting called on testin.

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration, you are replacing the current testin with the new values returned from your query. At the end it is probably empty because the last element in your list is not found, thus return an empty query. All the previous values have been dumped along the way. You should use concat (or union if you care about uniqueness) if you want to keep all the previous values.

```
IEnumerable<PreScreener> testin = new List<PreScreener>();
for (int i = 0; i < respondent.PreScreenerResponses.Count; i++)
{
    testin = testin.Concat(project.PreScreeners.Where(x => x.Id == respondent.PreScreenerResponses[i].PreScreenerId));
}
```